# Time limit exceeded Error codechef

Tags: time-complexity

This is the question 
   If Give an integer N . Write a program to obtain the sum of the first and last digit of this number.

Input

The first line contains an integer T, total number of test cases. Then follow T lines, each line contains an integer N.
    Output

Display the sum of first and last digit of N.
   Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
   1 ≤ N ≤ 1000000

Example

Input
  3 
  1234
  124894
  242323

Output
  5
  5
  5

Here is my code,When i submit the code it shows TLE error .I think the complexity of my code is O(1) Because as soon as the the number is entered the sum is calculated.I think i am calculating the complexity wrong.Some help on this would be great.Cheers!.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    char first,chr,chr_prv,temp;
    int test;
    cin>>test;
    temp=getchar(); // just to ignore the /n after cin>>test
    for(int i=0;i<test;i++)
    {

    int count=0;
    do
    {

        chr_prv=chr;
        chr=getchar();
        if(count==0)
            first=chr;
        count++;
    }while(chr!='\n');
    cout<<(int(first)+int(chr_prv)-96)<<endl;

    }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the input character-by-character which is slower. I would suggest take the whole number as a single integer input and simply add number%10 and number/str(number).length(). Do come back with results :) (I have purposely given simply a hint and not the whole code considering it is a codechef problem)

Comment: Yeah i knew that method before i just thgt this would be faster ☺ anyways thanx for the suggestion

Comment: What results did you get? And by the way, if your question is answered, please mark it as answered so that its easy for other SO members

Comment: results as in?i got an ac:)

Comment: cool, so the issue indeed was in the input-taking. Well done :)